# How do I iterate a function on two sides in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list called 'y' that is composed of the lowest chi squared values in a data table. So my list of y looks something like

> y = [0.014, 0.048, 3.53, 3.61, 9.08, 12.93, 13.15, 25.03, 26.55, 27.14]

I also have a list called "chi2".

In this list, I look for the exact location of where chi2 is equal to a specific value in the y[i] list. I do this using

```
index_min1 = np.where(chi2 == y[0])
index_min2 = np.where(chi2 == y[1])
index_min3 = np.where(chi2 == y[2])
index_min4 = np.where(chi2 == y[3])
index_min5 = np.where(chi2 == y[4])
index_min6 = np.where(chi2 == y[5])
index_min7 = np.where(chi2 == y[6])
index_min8 = np.where(chi2 == y[7])
index_min9 = np.where(chi2 == y[8])
index_min10 = np.where(chi2 == y[9])
```

I'm fairly new to python, and I was wondering if there was a better way I could iterate each side instead of manually typing out each line.

My thought process was something like

```
import numpy as np                          
import math                                    
from heapq import nsmallest
from numpy import arange


for i in arange(0,9,1):
    index_min+(i+1) = np.where(chi2 == y[i])
```

This is probably very wrong and I was wondering if there was a better way to do this than manual.

Comment: Would an array make more sense instead?

Comment: I don't need an array for this part of my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the left-hand side to be some kind of data structure supporting assignment to its elements, as many elements as you have in `y`.

For example, adapting your idea with a `list`:

```
indices = []

for i in arange(0, 9, 1):
    indices[i] = np.where(chi2 == y[i])
```

You can further simplify this with a 'list comprehension':

```
indices = [np.where(chi2 == y[i]) for i in arange(0, 9, 1)]
```

And finally, you didn't actually need `arange` since you can just iterate `y`:

```
indices = [np.where(chi2 == y_el) for y_el in y]
```

If you're more familiar with functional languages, an equivalent (still valid python) form is:

```
indices = list(map(lambda e: np.where(chi2 == e), y))
```

(Where the outer `list()` is only needed if you actually need it to be a list.)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the indices in another list, like this:

```
list_indices = []
for i in y:
    list_indices.append(np.where(chi2 == i))
```

Where `i`is an element in list `y`.

Answer (score 0):

A nice list generator should do it:

```
index_mins = [np.where(chi2 == yi) for yi in y]
```